# What does double question mark (??) mean in sql (postgres sql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

What does double question mark (`??`) mean in sql or sql query. (postgres sql).

My DB Server is Postgres and I am using columns that are of type jsonb.

I see a query that has `??` in it. Below is the query.

```
select rr.jdoc 
from table_with_jsonb rr 
where not (rr.jdoc ?? 'pivot')  
  and ((rr.jdoc->'mapping'->>'objectType')<>'meta');
```

Can some one explain what the `??` means and any references will be of great help.

Normally my understand is that - `?` is to allow Parameterized Query.
But this table   9.4 ref -> [FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) or 13.x ref -> [FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) adds more usage scenerios for `?`.
But still it does not say what `??` is.

PS: Plz ignore the doc references to 9.4. I am using 13.x currently.

Comment: AFAIR in some frameworks the doubled question mark is a placeholder for object name.

Comment: Are you really using the VERY old 9.4 version of postgresql or are you looking at the wrong docs?

Comment: @RichardHuxton - Plz ignore the doc references to 9.4. I am using 13.x currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as the `?` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) when used through JDBC.

JDBC uses `?`  for parameter placeholders and thus there needs to be a way to distinguish the operator from the parameter placeholder. So the Postgres JDBC driver allows to escape the `?` operator using `??` in a PreparedStatement.

I don't know if other technologies (ODBC, .Net) are using a similar mechanism.

Comment: i understand the prepared statements `?`. We set the value of `?` in the java code. But I am able to execute the query posted in question with out substituting `??` for any thing. `??` is part of the query and its executing.

Comment: @Vamsh Which tool do you use to run the query? Is it maybe a Java/JDBC based tool? Using `??` [does not work](https://dbfiddle.uk/RacJmfs8)

Comment: i am with DBeaver.

Comment: @Vamsh  As he said, `??` is to escape the placeholder behavior, and get through to the SQL operator named `?`.  So you don't have a placeholder, you have an operator named `?`, which behaves as in the link provided.

Comment: @Vamsh: DBEaver uses Java/JDBC if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: 99% sure I can yes - it uses java/JDBC. But i think here the `??` has got to do bit with jsonp too besides the reqular sql stuff. though not 100% sure.

Comment: @jjanes - seems that's the case..  `?? is to escape the placeholder behavior, and get through to the SQL operator named ?`.  I will take it.

Comment: if you like the Q. could you upvote.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name / @jjanes - for my own reference. Can you give any reference/blog that says that `?` in sql can be used as a escape char just like `back_slash` in regex.